# How to convert a ruby BigDecimal to a 2-decimal place string?

Tags: ruby

I want to convert a Ruby BigDecimal object to a nice, printable currency value. So I want it to print it to 2 decimal places. How can I do it?

As you can see, none of the following approaches worked:

```
irb(main):033:0> v = BigDecimal("7.1762")
=> #<BigDecimal:7fe97c1c9310,'0.71762E1',18(18)>
irb(main):034:0> v.to_s('2F')
=> "7.17 62"
irb(main):035:0> v.to_s('F')
=> "7.1762"
irb(main):036:0> v.to_s('%0.2F')
=> "0.71762E1"
irb(main):037:0> v.to_s('%0.2f')
=> "0.71762E1"
irb(main):038:0>
```

Which expression will just produce the string 7.17?

Comment: How do I do it without rounding? The solutions provided by other users both use rounding.

Answer (score 18):

Without rounding, and without converting to a `Float`, use `BigDecimal#truncate`:

```
v = BigDecimal("7.1762")
v.truncate(2).to_s('F')
# => "7.17"
```

If you need to show trailing zeroes, it gets more complicated:

```
v = BigDecimal("4.1")
v.truncate.to_s + '.' + sprintf('%02d', (v.frac * 100).truncate)
# => "4.10"
```

which uses `truncate` to convert to an Integer, always exact (and without rounding).

Comment: I just realized this doesn't work properly for the value of v = BigDecimal("4.2"). It doesn't pad with a trailing zero: https://gist.github.com/syedsaqibali/625742da4ec0a64584ed

Comment: (number.truncate(2).to_s('F') + '00')[/.*\..{2}/] also works

Answer (score 4):

Rounding without `round`

```
v = BigDecimal("7.1762")
sprintf("%.2f", v)
# => "7.18"

v = BigDecimal("4.1")
sprintf("%.2f", v)
# => "4.10"
```

if you want to truncate it to 2 decimal places

```
v = BigDecimal("7.1762")
sprintf("%.2f", v.truncate(2))
# => "7.17"

v = BigDecimal("4.1")
sprintf("%.2f", v.truncate(2))
# => "4.10"
```

Comment: Alternate syntax: `'%.2f' % v`