# How to return average value with precision(2) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a function `note.average(:value).to_s` that returns "4.5", and I want it to return "4.50" I think I run over most math functions but with out any luck so far :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a ruby BigDecimal to a 2-decimal place string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892378/how-to-convert-a-ruby-bigdecimal-to-a-2-decimal-place-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like this:

```
val = note.average(:value)    // 4.5
new_val = sprintf( "%0.02f", val) //4.50
```

Comment: Yep, was writing this too (about `String#%` which is mostly the same) but then realized that it converts the underlying number a to float, losing precision.

Comment: An example will explain better than I can. Try running this: `'%.2f' % BigDecimal('3333333333333333333333333333333333333.454')`

Comment: I wasted more than an hour for this ... I wonder what is so difficult in this, so it makes writing like  this so complicated.

Comment: @Kazik maybe the reason is that you wanted to convert a number to a different format. But numbers are not concerned with formats, in fact you wanted a string that represents a number with the format you want. This is a simplest way of doing this.