# Handling BigDecimal trailing zero's Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using `BigDecimal` values in my app as there are calculations to be made for goods in a shopping cart, I read that `BigDecimal` is preferred for this, compared to say integers or floats?

There is one scenario which I would like to address. When I have this for example

```
amount = BigDecimal.new("28.99")
amount      #=> #<BigDecimal:51d3120,'0.2899E2',18(18)>
amount.to_s #=> "28.99"
amount.to_f #=> 28.99
```

Which so far is expected behavior but when I do the following

```
amount = BigDecimal.new("28.00") || amount = BigDecimal.new("28") 
amount.to_s #=> "28.0"
amount.to_f #=> 28.0
```

Is this intended behavior ? In my db I have set the scale and precision

```
t.decimal :price, precision: 30, scale: 2
```

When I have a value of `28.00` saved in the database I would like to show in my view `28.00` and not `28.0`

Update

Just come across this post on SO [How to convert a ruby BigDecimal to a 2-decimal place string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892378/how-to-convert-a-ruby-bigdecimal-to-a-2-decimal-place-string) the solution being

```
v = BigDecimal("28.00")
v.truncate.to_s + '.' + sprintf('%02d', (v.frac * 100).truncate)
```

I guess this is the only way to handle it ?

Comment: For `v = BigDecimal("28.00")` `sprintf("%.2f", v)` should give `28.00`

Comment: Thanks again @eugen .. Works great. where would i find the documentation that explains all the options like `%.2f` ?

Comment: `BigDecimal.new("28.99").to_s` returns `"0.2899E2"` on my system

Comment: Never mind, Rails is patching `BigDecimal#to_s`, of course ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sprintf("%2.f", v)` should work. The options for `sprintf` can be found at

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf

Also, if you're using Rails, the `number_with_precision` helper is probably easier to use - you can find the documentation at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision

Comment: `number_with_precision` :-)

Comment: @Richlewis for amounts, there's also [`number_to_currenc`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency) and you should check out [money-rails](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails)

Comment: sprintf will actually convert it to a float, which could introduce precision error. try `sprintf("%.30f", BigDecimal('0.3'))
=> "0.299999999999999988897769753748"`